# Can this date be converted automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, date

I know that C# has some great date conversion tools.  What I'm I'm wondering is if I can automatically convert this string to a date object:

```
"Fri May 11 00:00:00 EDT 2012"
```

I'm thinking I'll have to manually parse the month, day, and year but I'm hoping there is an easier way built-in.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the time zone static, or will you be getting dates in different time zones?

Comment: The time zone is static.  I really don't even care about it.  I just want the month, day, and year.  The time is not important for the application.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryPraseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) to provide a custom format:

```
DateTime result;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(
        "Fri May 11 00:00:00 EDT 2012", 
        "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss EDT yyyy", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out result)) {
    // handle invalid date
}
```

All of the format options are listed on the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: The only issue with this is that the `"EDT"` portion is hard-coded, but it looks like that works for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx

Take a look at that.  Should help you out.

Example:

```
   // Convert a string returned by DateTime.ToString("R").
      String dateString = "Sat, 10 May 2008 14:32:17 GMT";
      ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse the string into a DateTime object :

```
String format = "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss EDT yyyy";
String dateString = "Fri May 11 00:00:00 EDT 2012";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You are right correct, seems not possible parsing the timezone... However i think my answer is not completely wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDateTime("Fri May 11 00:00:00 EDT 2012")` should work just fine.

Comment: Disregard.  I missed that the year was at the end of the string.